# using newaxis in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

```
A = np.array([[ 1, 2, 3], 
             [ 4, 5, 6], 
             [ 7, 8, 9],
             [10,11,12]])
B = A[:, np.newaxis]
print(B)
print(B.shape)
```

the output is

```
[[[ 1  2  3]]

 [[ 4  5  6]]

 [[ 7  8  9]]

 [[10 11 12]]]

(4L, 1L, 3L)
```

I have two questions:

1. Why are there extra brackets outside brackets, for example, `[[ 1  2  3]]`, so why it is not `[ 1  2  3]`?
2. what does `1L` mean? It looks like to me that `B` is a 4X3 matrix, so why is it not `(4L, 3L)`?

Comment: For clarity, think of that `B` as `B = A[:, np.newaxis, :]`.  You have added a dimension in the middle of the 2 existing dimensions of `A`.

Answer (score 4):

Refer to numpy reference document (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html),
Each newaxis object in the selection tuple serves to expand the dimensions of the resulting selection by one unit-length dimension. The added dimension is the position of the newaxis object in the selection tuple.

1. Here, each bracket represent one dimension, extra bracket is caused by newaxis.
2. 1L means the dimension increased by newaxis.

Answer (score 2):

The "extra" bracket and the 1L are  there for the same reason: your use of `np.newaxis` inserted a new dimension of extent 1 into the array shape—in other words, you transformed a two-dimensional 4x3 array into a three-dimensional 4x1x3 array.

Each of the 4 "rows" of `B`contains a two-dimensional 1x3 array, such as

```
[[4,5,6]]
```

whereas each corresponding row of `A` was just a one-dimensional array of length 3:

```
[4,5,6]
```

Hence the extra brackets.

Comment: That's what `np.newaxis` is supposed to do, so I guess it begs the question: what did you expect instead?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One thing I still don't understand is, why there is comma ',' in A but there is no ',' to separate rows in B?

Comment: There has to be a comma when defining an array (it's not valid Python syntax without it). But for display purposes, I guess `numpy` omits the commas when *printing* an array sometimes, presumably to reduce visual clutter.

Comment: @Dong There is no comma separation in B because you are printing it using a print command. Try just typing B in python interpreter and you will see a comma separated array. Numpy prints an array where each slice is separated by an empty line. For more details see [numpy doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html) and search for Printing Array.